# Downloaded Tableau dashboard too narrow. Narrower than online published version that was downloaded

Tags: download, tableau-api, dashboard

I am trying to work with a published Tableau dashboard.  I download it and open it with Tableau desktop and it is too narrow.  Not the same width as it was on line.  Many of the text boxes are truncated.  How can I get it to download and appear locally the same as it shows when published?

Comment: share some images atleast

Comment: Many tableau workbooks adjust the content to the size of the window they are displayed in. You need to edit those settings and/or use a bigger window to display the worksheet.